# Does comparing to Math.Min or Math.Max short-circuit?

Tags: c#, short-circuiting

When comparing to a minimum or maximum of two numbers/functions, does C# short-circuit if the case is true for the first one and would imply truth for the second? Specific examples of these cases are

```
if(x < Math.Max(y, z()))
```

and

```
if(x > Math.Min(y, z()))
```

Since `Math.Max(y, z())` will return a value at least as large as y, if x < y then there is no need to evaluate z(), which could take a while. Similar situation with `Math.Min`.

I realize that these could both be rewritten along the lines of

```
if(x < y || x < z())
```

in order to short-circuit, but I think it's more clear what the comparison is without rewriting. Does this short-circuit?

Comment: Assume you call `if( x > XYZ(y,z()))` How can compiler know the result of XYZ ? Max,Min,Average or anything else?

Comment: @L.B Great point, I had not considered this in that way.

Comment: Also, the "short-circuited" expression may not be equivalent, depending on how `Min` and `Max` handle NaN.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the compiler knows nothing about the semantics of Min or Max that would allow it to break the rule that arguments are evaluated before the method is called.

If you wanted to write your own, you could do so easily enough:

```
static bool LazyLessThan(int x, int y, Func<int> z)
{
    return x < y || x < z();
}
```

and then call it

```
if (LazyLessThan(x, y, z))
```

or

```
if (LazyLessThan(x, y, ()=>z()))
```

Or for that matter:

```
static bool LazyRelation<T>(T x, T y, Func<T> z, Func<T, T, bool> relation)
{
    return relation(x, y) || relation(x, z());
}
...
if (LazyRelation(x, y, ()=>z, (a,b)=> a < b)))
```

Comment: That last example would have been great, if it were possible to add a default argument, like so:
static bool LazyRelation<T>(T x, T y, Func<T> x, Func<T, T, bool> relation = (a,  b)=>a < b)

Comment: +1 Great answer, but let's be honest - is all of that more readable / maintainable than `if(x < y || x < z())` which the OP suggested himself?

Comment: I'd say it's less readable, because it replaces a basic idiom with a function whose definition you have to read in order to understand the code.

Answer (score 10):

No, it doesn't short circuit and z() will always be evaluated.  If you want the short circuiting behavior you should rewrite as you have done.

Comment: The reason for this is because the runtime has no way of knowing what the effects of `Max()` and `Min()` are. **You** do, which allows you to rewrite in a more performant way.

Answer (score 5):

`Math.Min()` and `Math.Max()` are methods just like any other. They have to be evaluated in order to return the value which will be used as the second argument in the comparison. If you want short-circuiting then you will have to write the condition using the `||` operator as you have demonstrated.

Answer (score 3):

(Nothing particularly new to add, but I figured I'd share the results of a test I ran on it.)

Math.Max() could easily be inlined by the CLR's just-in-time compiler and from there I was curious whether it might further optimize the code in such a way that it is short-circuited.

So I whipped up a microbenchmark that evaluates the two expressions 1,000,000 times each.
For z(), I used a function that calculates Fib(15) using the recursive method.  Here are the results of running the two:

```
x < Math.Max(y, z()) :   8097 ms
x < y || x < z()     :     29 ms
```

I'm guessing the CLR won't transform the code in any way that prevents method calls from executing, because it doesn't know (and doesn't check to see if) the routine has any side effects.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesnt short circuit, at least at the C# compiler level. `Math.Min` or `Math.Max` are two ordinary static method calls and the compiler will not optimize in that sense.

The order of evaluation of the code will be: z(), Math.Max, x > ...

If you really want to make sure, check out the IL code.